# How to Scrape Inner level url using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I created a scrapy spider watching some online video. It scrapes profile url from a website. I want to extend this to **scrape** data like address, name, phone,website url from each profile url scraped.

I was thinking to create to separate scrapers. One for scraping Profile url. And the second one to scrape the data from the scraped first url.

Is there any other solution?

Here is my spider that scrapes profile urls.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import ...scraperItem

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = ['https:// ...']
    page_number = 15

    def parse(self, response):
        items=...scraperItem()
       ..._url=response.css('a.header-5.text-unbold ::attr(href)').extract_first()

        items['..._url']= ..._url
        yield items
        next_page = 'https:/...'+str(...SpiderSpider.page_number)
        if ...SpiderSpider.page_number <= 150:
            ...SpiderSpider.page_number += 15
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another parse method (eg. `parse_profile`) to scrape the additional data. E.g.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    url = response.css('a.header-5.text-unbold ::attr(href)').extract_first()

    yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_profile)

    # next_page = ...
    if self.page_number <= 150:
        self.page_number += 15
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

def parse_profile(self, response)
    item = HouzzscraperItem()
    item['houzz_url'] = response.url
    # item['address'] = ...
    # item['name'] = ...
    # item['phone'] = ...
    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks. What is that three dots ... means?

Comment: It means you will need to fulfill then with valid code :)

Comment: No worries. You already had that part figured out.
Regarding your error, I'm not able to see the whole thing. Could you paste it into a text tool, like pastebin.org ?

Comment: oh, now I see that `parse` and `parse_profile` are not correctly indented. It seems like they belong to the scope outside the class. Put them both inside by indenting their `def`s aligned with the `page_number` attribute.

Comment: I see. It scraping only one profile each page because `extract_first`. Iterate over `extract()` then you will get all of them.

Comment: Also, I think you should avoid increment `self.page_number`, since the requests are asynchronous and it could skip some result pages. Instead pass it with `meta`. See the example above.

Comment: (I've been using a dict instead of your item class, but you can undo that part :) )

Comment: That works like a charm. What if i need to start url with a page number other than zero? Like self.page_number 1500 ? Can I just replace number and use it?

Comment: You could use [`start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) instead.